# Bootstrap 4 : How to use full with for span area close to label

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm looking to modify the width of a span close to his label.

I want to display several group { label / data } on the same line.
So, I splited the rol with 4 col, then want to apply a special width to a span. But no way, the size doesnt change ...
Was working in bootstrap 3. ..

Here the code :

```
<div class="row">   
    <div class="col-xl-4">
        <label class="">Batch ID : </label>
        <span class="border padding_right5 padding_left5 col-xl-3">4444</span>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-xl-4">
         <label class="">Etat : </label>
         **<span class="border border_etat_batch statut_green">En Cours</span>**
    </div>      
    <div class="col-xl-2">
        <label>Ligne : </label>
        <span class="border border_data">1</span>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-xl-2 text-right">
        <label>Cuve : </label>
        <span class="border border_data">B1</span>
    </div>                                                                                                                                                      
</div>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjl9S.jpg)

Comment: Any suggestion to do that properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootsrap v4 does not have `-xl` classes, the alternative is to use `col-{num}` for xtra small devices or use `col-sm-{num}` for small devices

Also to fill the space of the span tag, use `flex-fill` class from bootstrap flex utilities [link here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/)

```
<div class="col-4 d-flex">
         <label class="">Etat : </label>
         **<span class="border border_etat_batch statut_green flex-fill">En Cours</span>**
    </div>
```

```css
.statut_green{
background:green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">   
    <div class="col-4">
        <label class="">Batch ID : </label>
        <span class="border padding_right5 padding_left5 col-3">4444</span>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-4 d-flex">
         <label class="">Etat : </label>
         **<span class="border border_etat_batch statut_green flex-fill">En Cours</span>**
    </div>      
    <div class="col-2">
        <label>Ligne : </label>
        <span class="border border_data">1</span>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-2 text-right">
        <label>Cuve : </label>
        <span class="border border_data">B1</span>
    </div>                                                                                                                                                      
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That works .. still need to learn Bootstrap 4 change :)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```css
.col-filled {
  display: flex;
}

.d-inline {
  flex: 1 1 auto
}

.statut_green {
  background: green;
  flex: 1 1 auto
}
```

```html
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">   
    <div class="col-xl-4">
        <label class="">Batch ID : </label>
        <span class="border padding_right5 padding_left5 col-xl-3">4444</span>
    </div>    
    <div class="col-filled col-xl-4">
         <label class="">Etat : </label>
         **<span class="border border_etat_batch statut_green">En Cours</span>**
    </div>      
    <div class="col-filled col-xl-2">
        <label class='d-inline'>Ligne : </label>
        <span class="d-inline border border_data">1</span>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-xl-2 text-right">
        <label>Cuve : </label>
        <span class="border border_data">B1</span>
    </div>                                                                                                                                                      
</div>
```

**[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/webdevkumar/r214fzns/1/)**